# Postgresql - Composite Key and two tables, or just 1 wide table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I am constructing a horse racing database, but I am struggling figuring out the best possible design.

**Option 1)**

2 Tables, 1 for "race", the other for "horses"

This would look like this

Table 1: ID | Date | Time | Race Name | Weekday | Course | Distance | Going | Class | Pricemoney | Number of Starters | Finishing time | Type Of Race

**Table 2:**

Race ID | Finishing Number 1 | Horse Name| Jockey | Trainer | Weight | Age | Sectional Speed | **and so on**
Race ID | Finishung Number 2 | .....

**Question to this Design:** How do I define a Composite Primary Key on Date, Time, Course and Racename and links this as a foreign key to Race ID in Table 2? I use Postgresql (via. pgadmin4)

**Option 2:**

One wide table, with the race data, and then the horses following on one row (finishing number 1 | 2 | 3 .... until up to 30 on very rare occasions)

Problem with this design is that not every race has the same number of starters, so there would be a lot of *null* entries in the rows from horse number 8 to 30.

Advantage would be, that i would not have to join the tables for queries, Most queries would require a complete join, as nearly all the data in this table is required on every query.

The table would consist of roughly 360-400 columns (wide) and up to 20.000 (maybe more) rows.

**Question:** Would this be problem performance wise? I would make only a few queries a day

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wide table is the datawarehouse approach. This may be appropriate when dealing with billions of rows. But datawarehouses often get their data from pure relational databases, so it is ensured that data is consistent.

Joins are something an RDBMS is made for. They are usually fast. Don't worry about this. my advice is: Build a proper normalized database.

There are races and horses. In one race there are multiple horses and one horse can participate in multiple races. That is an m:n relation for which you need a bridge table.

The tables:

- horse (horse_id, horse_name, birth_date, trainer, ...)
- race (race_id, date_time, race_name, course, distance, price_money, ...)
- participation (horse_id, race_id, jockey, weight, position, ...)